# Column Expanding When Adding Text Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have noticed a problem when running the following HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <style>
    
    .card
    {
        background-color: #EFF3FC!important;
    }
    
    .btnBlue
    {
        background: #1467ba;
        height: 25px;
        width: 70px;
        font-size: 14px; 
        color: white;   
    }
    
    </style> 
    
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card card-block w-100 h-100">
                
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFF3FC;">
                    
                                
                                
                            </nav>

                            <p class="h3 text-primary">
                                Sign In
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </p>
                
                            <form action="{% url 'landing' %}" method="POST">

    
                                <input type="email" id="Username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                                <br> <br> 
    
                                <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                <br> <br>
    

                                <h6>
                                <p class="text-danger"> 
                                    <small> The Username or Password you entered does not match our records. Please try again. </small> 
                                    <br>
                                </p>
                                </h6>

    
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-center btn-sm">Log In</button>

                            </form>

                            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-block w-100 h-100">
                        <p class="h3 text-primary">
                            <br> <br> 
                            Sign Up
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            Don't have an account yet? Enter your username and we'll send you a link for a secure sign-up experience!
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                            <br>
                        </div>

                        <h6>
                        <p class="text-danger" hidden> 
                            <small> Please check the email you've entered and try again! </small>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        </h6>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-center btn-sm">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Columns (md-4 and md-8) expand/compress whenever I add text. For example, try removing the line `<small> The Username or Password you entered does not match our records. Please try again. </small>` . The left container will suddenly shrink in size. Add the line back and the container will expand. How do I solve this problem? Ideally I don't want the width to change regardless of adding/deleting that line.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your first div in there classes i changed i like this try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <style>
    
    .card
    {
        background-color: #EFF3FC!important;
    }
    
    .btnBlue
    {
        background: #1467ba;
        height: 25px;
        width: 70px;
        font-size: 14px; 
        color: white;   
    }
    
    </style> 
    
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid d-block  text-center" style="position: absolute;top
        :50%;transform: translateY(-50%);">
            <div class="row no-gutters ">
                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <div class="card card-block w-100 h-100">
                
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFF3FC;">
                    
                                
                                
                            </nav>

                            <p class="h3 text-primary">
                                Sign In
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </p>
                
                            <form action="{% url 'landing' %}" method="POST">

    
                                <input type="email" id="Username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                                <br> <br> 
    
                                <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                <br> <br>
    

                                <h6>
                                <!-- <p class="text-danger"> 
                                    <small> The Username or Password you entered does not match our records. Please try again. </small> 
                                    <br>
                                </p> -->
                                </h6>

    
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-center btn-sm">Log In</button>

                            </form>

                            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card card-block w-100 h-100">
                        <p class="h3 text-primary">
                            <br> <br> 
                            Sign Up
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>

                        <!-- <p>
                            Don't have an account yet? Enter your username and we'll send you a link for a secure sign-up experience!
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p> -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
                            <br>
                        </div>

                        <h6>
                        <p class="text-danger" hidden> 
                            <small> Please check the email you've entered and try again! </small>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                        </h6>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary align-center btn-sm">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```